# How do i write an NgRx 8 Effect that triggers an action from a promise

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, observable, ngrx

I am struggling to grasp NgRx Effects.

Using the latest release, version 8, i have written the following effect which combines the observable with a promise and am struggling to grasp how to write it correctly.

Is this guaranteed to catch all possible errors?

```
authLogin$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.authLogin),
    switchMap(async(action) => {
      try {
        const userState = await this.loginService.login(action.username, action.password);
        return AuthActions.authSuccess(userState);
      }
      catch (error) {
        return AuthActions.authLoginError({
          error: error
        });
      }
    })
  ),{ resubscribeOnError: false });
```

I am also not clear on whether or not i should be using the last bit of this configuration: `{ resubscribeOnError: false }` Does this mean subsequent execution will create an entirely new observable?

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this `try catch` will catch all errors, cause I've only seen Promises with `.then().catch()`, but why don't you convert this Promise to an Observable? It'd make your `pipe` easier to write and to write properly.

Use your `switchMap` to return an Observable from your Promise with

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';

...
switchMap(action => from(this.loginService.login(action.username, action.password)))
...
```

After that you can have your `catchError`, an Observable operator from RxJs. You receive the error and a property called `caught`, which is the source observable (from docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError)). Where you can

```
...
catchError((err, caught$) => {
  this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.authLoginError({ error: error }));
  return caught$;
})
...
```

The `return caught$` is important cause you prevent your Effect from dying if an error occurs. You don't need to handle like that on NgRx 8, you could simple

```
...
catchError((err, caught$) => {
  return of(new AuthActions.authLoginError({ error: error })));
})
...
```

But then you'd need your `{ resubscribeOnError: true }` (which is the default value). This is a feature that resubscribe on your Effect if you don't handle errors, once again preventing it from dying.

And then, after your `catchError`, you can have a simple `map` to return on success, like this

```
...
map(userState => new AuthActions.authSuccess(userState))
```

So, your finished code will look like this

```
authLogin$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActions.authLogin),
  switchMap(action => from(this.loginService.login(action.username, action.password))),
  catchError((err, caught$) => of(new AuthActions.authLoginError({ error: error })))),
  map(userState => new AuthActions.authSuccess(userState))
)); // no resubscribeOnError since default value is true
```

I'd say this is a better approach since utilizes an Observable for your service call, you have operators separating responsibilities and makes NgRx happy.

Comment: Couple of things, i believe we should remove `caught$` and `err` should be named `error`

Comment: Yes, of course, if `caught$` is not being used there's no reason for maintaining it there. About `err`, one can freely name it `error` as it fits, but on docs found here https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError the name of the param is `err`, so I see no problem keeping it as `err`.

Comment: This effect is not triggered for second time. Please help how to trigger multiple times using ngrx v8 effects.